# Check if two lists are equal with different type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a problem with checking for list equality.
 I have the following list:

```
List<RequestDetailViewModel> requestDetail
```

that RequestDetailViewModel is :

```
public int PropertiesValueID { get; set; }
public int UnitID { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public int PropertyID { get; set; }
```

and i have another list "reqList":

```
var reqList = (from p in db.RequestDetail
                        group new 
                        { p.PropertyID, p.UnitID , p.Value , p.PropertiesValueID }
                         by p.RequestID into reqG
                        select reqG
                       );
```

i want to check list equality Like this:

```
foreach (var item in reqList)
{

        if (requestDetail equals item)

        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can implement `IComparable` for your class and then use `SequenceEqual` method. Also, do not need to create anonymous type whil grouping, your `reqList` argument type must be `RequestDetailViewModel`.

Comment: Your `reqList` would be better off by not creating an anonymous type and instead just grouping requests, it then should be come much easier for you

Comment: Why are you creating an anonymous type? You use all the properties, so you might as wel group it into an object of the same type.

Comment: Your `reqList` is not a list.

Comment: @DionV. whats you'r idea? please tell me in detail...

Comment: Why don't you use `group new RequestDetailViewModel`? Makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @GertArnold please give me a sample ...

Comment: First try the grouping into a `RequestDetailViewModel`. Then you have two lists of identical types. You should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your reqList select:

```
var reqList = (from p in db.RequestDetail
                      group new 
             { p.PropertyID, p.UnitID , p.Value , p.PropertiesValueID }
               by p.RequestID into reqG
                select new RequestDetailViewModel{
                  PropertyID = reqG.PropertyID, UnitID = reqG.UnitID ,
                  Value = reqG.Value , 
                  PropertiesValueID = reqG.PropertiesValueID 
                });
```

Will return `List<RequestDetailViewModel>`

Implement `IComparable` for your `RequestDetailViewModel` class then use `SequenceEqual` to compare two lists

Comment: you can't get PropertyID,UnitID,Value, PropertiesValueID from reqG like this !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop your View Model list, linq-querying the domain list for each item. Something like:

```
foreach (var detail in requestDetail)
{
    var reqListEqualItems = (from p in db.RequestDetail
                             where p.PropertyID == details.PropertyID &&
                                   p.UnitID == details.UnitID &&
                                   p.Value == details.Value &&
                                   p.PropertyID == details.PropertyID);
}
```

Something like that should give you the Domain Object items for each ViewModel item.

Answer (score 0):

I would update the `RequestDetailViewModel` as follows:

```
public class RequestDetailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ResultDetail resultDetail;

  public RequestDetailViewModel(ResultDetail resultDetail)
  {
    this.resultDetail = resultDetail;
  }

  public ResultDetail
  {
     get
     {
       return this.resultDetail;
     }
  }

  public int PropertiesValueID 
  {
    get
    {
     return this.resultDetail.PropertiesValueID;
    }
    set
    {
       this.resultDetail.PropertiesValueID = value;
       this.RaisePropertyChanged("PropertiesValueID");
    }
  }

  public int UnitID 
  {
    get
    {
       return this.resultDetail.UnitID ;
    }
    set
    {
       this.resultDetail.UnitID = value;
       this.RaisePropertyChanged("UnitID");
    }
  }

  public string Value
  {
    get
    {
       return this.resultDetail.Value;
    }
    set
    {
       this.resultDetail.Value= value;
       this.RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
    }
  }

  public int PropertyID 
  {
    get
    {
       return this.resultDetail.PropertyID ;
    }
    set
    {
       this.resultDetail.PropertyID = value;
       this.RaisePropertyChanged("PropertyID");
    }
  }    
}
```

I'd also implement IEquatable in your DB model. 
and I'd do the check like this:

```
foreach (var item in reqList)
{
    if (requestDetail.ResultDetail.Equals(item))
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

or better yet

```
return reqList.Any(item=> item.Equals(requestDetail.ResultDetail));
```